# When transmitting data using UDP is it necessary to include the message length as part of the message?

Tags: .net, udp, udpclient

I have a client who is looking to reduce the number of bytes transmitted over the wire to the absolute minimum. When creating a udpClient class and invoking the receive method, a byte array is returned. Currently I'm using receiveBytes.Length to get the number of bytes in the message.

However, under heavy load with multiple messages coming in, it's been suggested that this is not sufficient, justifying the need to send the packet length as the first 2 bytes of the message.

Can I depend on either a complete packet or no packet being received, and hence rely on the Length property?

**Edit**

Thanks for all the comments.

Using UDP is in addition to TCP. TCP is used when we need to implement sequence and a guarantee. UDP will be used for data that is good to have in any order but not critical. Yes, I know it means adding OTT encryption. My question was simply can I depend on ONLY complete packets arriving.

Comment: you can depend on a complete packet being received.  You just can't depend on ALL the packets being received.

Comment: If you need sequence number and checksum, then you need TCP....

Comment: UDP itself has a checksum to make sure it's not a corrupted packet.  You hand-rolling this is a waste of time, unless you are actually implementing UDP yourself (I don't think that's what the OP is doing).  A sequence number doesn't make a lot of sense, because the other messages in a sequence may never arrive.  If you need this kind of functionality to be workable, then you need TCP.

Comment: L.B. video is a perfect example of why you DO NOT need a sequence number.  You play frames as they arrive and don't worry about missing frames  To the end user it looks like a moving picture even if a frame is lost.

Comment: sounds like you should've used TCP to handle that work for you :)

Comment: MPEG-TS is a protocol... UDP is a protocol... the OP's question is about UDP, not MPEG-TS

Comment: L.B., no one called you an idiot.  I think you are confused about terms like "packet".  What a UDP Packet contains is well known.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol.  Another protocol can be contained in the data portion of a UDP packet, but we shouldn't be discussing other protocols here.

Comment: from OP's recent edit, " My question was simply can I depend on ONLY complete packets arriving."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each UDP packet is delivered independently, and with no guarantee that any other packet will arrive.

How would you (on receiving one) know to wait for another one, and what could you do if it never turned up? Long way of saying, you'll receive the sent message or none at all.

Comment: Specifically, when I receive the packet, will the the packet contain ALL of the bytes that left the originating machine?

Comment: Yes. It has to. There are no options in UDP for fragmentation to occur - each received set of bytes represents a single sent set of bytes.

Comment: @L.B - yes, you can. But, if the requirement was in-order delivery, that was not specifically evident in the question. And once you need in-order or guaranteed delivery, you start thinking about TCP rather than UDP, and suitable framing.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I added an edit to clarify I'm using TCP where order or guarantee is needed. This is a second layer of data, a fact I clearly missed from the question.